# How do i prevent Redux Dispatch from getting called on mount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

ProductHover gets rendered every time i hover an parent element. I need to dispatch an action to Redux but that dispatch action gets called everytime the component renders. I want to dispatch it on click.

```
const ProductHover = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return (
    <div className={styles.producthover}>
      <div className={styles.addcart}>
        <span>&#xe07a;</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.viewproduct}>
        <span>VIEW PRODUCT</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.favorite}>
        <span onClick={dispatch(addFavorite(1))}>&#xe089;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the action that gets dispatched is `addFavorite`, then it needs to be invoked as a callback. As-is, it will always be invoked immediately when the component is rendered/re-rendered, and then later when you click nothing will happen.

```
() => dispatch(addFavorite(1))
```

Code

```
const ProductHover = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className={styles.producthover}>
      <div className={styles.addcart}>
        <span>&#xe07a;</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.viewproduct}>
        <span>VIEW PRODUCT</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.favorite}>
        <span onClick={() => dispatch(addFavorite(1))}>&#xe089;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your are firing function when component render instead you need to add callback when click is fired like this:

```
const ProductHover = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
const addToFavorite = ()=>dispatch(addFavorite(1))
  return (
    <div className={styles.producthover}>
      <div className={styles.addcart}>
        <span>&#xe07a;</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.viewproduct}>
        <span>VIEW PRODUCT</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.favorite}>
        <span onClick={addToFavorite}>&#xe089;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Such a basic mistake... It's late here, sorry and thank you :)